# ExtJS7: How to test `onAppUpdate` in dev or testing environment

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs7

ExtJS v7.1 based application has `onAppUpdate` function and some other methods like `onLaunch` mentioned in documantation [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/classic/Ext.app.Application.html) for classic application. However in development and in testing environment these never gets fired. Is it as intended, if yes then how we can test `onAppUpdate` in dev or testing build. If no, then what could have gone wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by enabling **Local Storage Cache** for a specific build in your *app.json* file.

Example for the testing build:

```
/**
* Settings specific to testing builds.
*/
"testing": {
    "cache": {
         "enable": true
    }
},
```

Every build on the testing environment will now call the onAppUpdate() function.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you'll never see an `onAppUpdate` event triggered if you are using a dev build; it needs to be packaged (with caching enabled, as @ground_call points out). The point of `onAppUpdate` is that you've got a cached version which is older than what's now available - no cache, no `onAppupdate`

If you're willing to trust the infrastructure, and just test what *your* app does, you can always trigger the onAppUpdate event programmatically, either in a test script or from the JavaScript console.